# How to use Greensock plugin in vue-cli Webpack project (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, gsap

I've set up a vue.js project using vue-cli webpack.
I want to use Greensock animation plugin in my project so I ran

```
npm install greensock --save
```

and it's installed.

in `main.js` file I added

```
import { TweenMax } from "greensock"
```

I don't know if this makes Greensock plugin available as I get syntax error at `Tweenmax.to ...` in a component file

```
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  el: '.hello',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  },
  method: {
    TweenMax.to(el, 2, {opacity: 0})
  }
}
```

I didn't come across a documentation for using Greensock in vue.js project so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: method should be methods, then you need to wrap your library call from a method: myMethod(){TweenMax ecc ecc ecc

Comment: Your observation was right. I got it to work by wrapping a method. And, yes, I had a typo, too. If you could post it as an answer I am happy to pick and close the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to make two change:

- fix a typo in your methods, `method` should be `methods`
- inside your methods you should define a function which execute your logic

  method: {
      TweenMax.to(el, 2, {opacity: 0})
    }

will be:

```
 methods: {
    myTween(){
      ///...put here your ui logic
    }
  }
```

all the best